# Gradient of a matrix of only constants

Tags: matrices

I am confused about calculating the gradient of a matrix when the matrix is composed of only constant values.
I'm doing an online interactive course in C++ that requires me to find this. I can't even do the math to get to the programming part.

Here's an example input/output:
input:
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
19
output: gradient =-30

Thank you!

Comment: Did you google "How to find gradient"?

Comment: The gradient of a matrix isn't defined. You can only take the gradient of a real-valued function. So perhaps you need a clearer description of the function that's associated to your matrix.

Comment: @Crystal, can I ask what the course is? The reason I am asking is that I have found a lot of online courses like machine learning or so dealing with gradients etc, but I have always been looking for one based on C++ and never found one. Everyone I know uses Matlab, Octave, etc.

Comment: @user25004 t's a very beginner level course in C++ found here: [http://www.programmr.com/practice/](http://www.programmr.com/practice/) I think you have to log in to look at it but it's free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be missing what the question wants.
Typically what shows up, specially in coding, like for gradient descent or so, is to compute the gradient of a function at some point. The point, could be 1d, vector, or in your case a matrix.

It is a good idea to check what the function is in your case. (Say a loss or objective function, etc)